# Pure Birth Process Probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes

I have no clue how to proceed with this question. Please help me in deriving the differential equations! Thanks very much... I really appreciate it :)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete derivation of the differential equations. [Suggestion: After each step below, try completing the derivation on your own.]

$$
P_0 (t + h) = {\rm P}(N(t + h)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm even}|N(t)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm even})P_0 (t) +  {\rm P}(N(t + h)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm even}|N(t)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm odd})P_1 (t).
$$
Put $\Delta_t(h) = N(t+h)-N(t)$.
Then, as $h \downarrow 0$,
$$
P_0 (t + h) = {\rm P}(\Delta_t(h)=0|N(t)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm even})P_0 (t) + {\rm P}(\Delta_t(h)=1|N(t)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm odd})P_1 (t) + o(h).
$$
Hence,
$$
P_0 (t + h) = [1 - {\rm P}(\Delta_t(h)=1|N(t)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm even})]P_0 (t) + {\rm P}(\Delta_t(h)=1|N(t)\;{\rm is} \; {\rm odd})P_1 (t) + o(h),
$$
leading to
$$
P_0 (t + h) = (1-\beta h)P_0 (t) + \alpha h P_1 (t) + o(h).
$$
Rearranging gives
$$
\frac{{P_0 (t + h) - P_0 (t)}}{h} = \alpha P_1 (t) - \beta P_0 (t) + \frac{{o(h)}}{h}.
$$
Letting $h \downarrow 0$ thus gives
$$
P'_0 (t) = \alpha P_1 (t) - \beta P_0 (t) .
$$
Similarly,
$$
P'_1 (t) = \beta P_0 (t) - \alpha P_1 (t) ,
$$
which also follows trivially from $P_0 (t) + P_1 (t) = 1$.